# Unique 8 digit incremental number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a number which will ultimately be stored as string(varchar). e.g.

1. First - ABC00000001
2. Second- ABC00000002
   .........................
   I am able to generate character string as expected. Now the problem is,incremental number.

What i am trying to do is get the last number stored e.g. ABC00000009 and generate the next number that is ABC00000010. How to do the same?

If i extract integers from this than i will get 1 or 10,how to make it according to 8 digit format.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Store the number and string pattern in different column. If string pattern is static(always ABC) than you don't need to store it in table.

Comment: @ArvindDhakad,i can't store them as seperate due to current structure. All i have is a varchar column where i'm supposed to store the final string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course if changing the table structure is not an option, you can try this:

```
DECLARE @lastValue VARCHAR(15) = 'ABC00000001'
SELECT CONCAT('ABC',  RIGHT(100000000 + CAST(RIGHT(@lastValue, 8) AS INT) + 1, 8)) 

Result
-----------
ABC00000002
```

Comment: Excellent. That's what i was looking for. You saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2645738 glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create an identity column.  This will increment (usually by 1, but not always).  Then create a computed column:

```
alter table t add generated_number as
    ('ABC' + right(replicate('0', 8) + cast(idcol as varchar(255)), 8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same approach [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) has taken, I just prefer to use math where possible instead of string concatenation. My answer is different only because I add `id` value to `100000000` instead of using replicate.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
  , some_value sysname UNIQUE
  , super_column AS 'ABC' + RIGHT(100000000 + id, 8));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.test (some_value)
VALUES ('some_value_1'), ('some_value_2');

SELECT *
FROM dbo.test AS T;
```

Result:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id |  some_value  | super_column |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | some_value_1 | ABC00000001  |
|  2 | some_value_2 | ABC00000002  |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Couldn't you just seed the IDENTITY with 100000000 as the first value instead?

Comment: Didn't think of that. I don't see any reason not to do it. Good catch, both ways are ok. Depends what OP actually wants, if he wants to have identity values - maybe starting it at 1 makes more sense.